# TFS 2015 - Checkin to a specific Tag

Tags: c#, tfs, merge, checkin

I have a `TeamFoundationServer` 2015 with one Project (let's name it ProjectA).
ProjectA contains three different solutions (let's name them SolutionA, SolutionB, SolutionC)

Under this TFS-Project (`ProjectA`) there are different Branches (let's name them `BranchA`, `BranchB`, etc)

Each week we do a merge from BranchA to BranchB.

Now the interesting part:
Within one week I do update SourceCode of SolutionA and SolutionB.
Now when the weekly merge appears I only want for example to merge all changes made to SolutionA.
To do this I manually check all my changesets which belong to SolutionA and then I merge them.
This is often very time consuming and the question is if this can be achieved easier.

So I am looking for some kind of way to assign my source-code to some specific tag or something like that. So all I do is then: search for the tag `"XYZ"` and merge all changesets which belong to that.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: But unless you can absolutely guarantee that tag is applied to **every** SolutionA checkin and **only** SolutionA checkins, then you still have to review them. Can't you merge everything and then undo the changes to the other solutions?

Comment: yeah that idea with the "tag" is not good. I can merge everything but undoing the changes forces me again to know which changes were made to SolutionA and which to SolutionB. It would be great to have some kind of automatically assignment when checking in for example to SolutionA to have a tag or whatever and the same thing for SolutionB.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you just want to merge changes only in solution A to another branch. You have to manually pick up the changesets you need.

One way is using **changeset comment** to quickly distinguish which belongs to solution A and which belongs B. This will help you reduce the time. Just need to check the comments instead of go through the changeset details.

[image]

You could use check in policy to make check-in comments mandatory. Details please refer to this blog-- How to make check-in comments mandatory.

---

Besides, you could also use a **workspace version** when you do the merge. Create two different workspaces, one for solution A, another for B. When you want to merge changes only for solution A, you could just merge your latest version of your local workspace.

This way has some limitations, unless you are the only one contributing to solution A. Otherwise you need to get latest from server side to get others' changes before merge. You also may merge some changes has not check in yet.

Comment: i am currently using comments to distinguish the projects, thx for ur help ;)